# Flutter : how to change from model to list

Tags: android, flutter, asp.net-web-api2

I want integrate Flutter with an ASP.NET API. the problem is when I create search by example, the example use list instead of model, but i dont know how to do it, can i using serach from model instead. this is my model

```
class listmodel {
  String? drainageid;
  int? datacount;
  int? resultcount;
  String? page;
  List<Rows>? rows;
  String? error;

  listmodel(
      {this.drainageid,
      this.datacount,
      this.resultcount,
      this.page,
      this.rows});

  listmodel.withError(String errorMessage) {
    error = errorMessage;
  }

  listmodel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    drainageid = json['drainageid'];
    datacount = json['datacount'];
    resultcount = json['resultcount'];
    page = json['page'];
    if (json['rows'] != null) { rows = 
    (json['rows'] as List).map((e) => Rows.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList()..sort(
      (a, b) => b.dateofinsp!.compareTo(a.dateofinsp!));
     } 
  }

  factory listmodel.fromJsonn(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    var _rows;
    if (json['rows'] != null) { _rows = 
    (json['rows'] as List).map((e) => Rows.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList()..sort(
      (a, b) => b.dateofinsp!.compareTo(a.dateofinsp!));
     } 
    return listmodel(
    drainageid : json['drainageid'],
    datacount : json['datacount'],
    resultcount : json['resultcount'],
    page : json['page'],
    rows: _rows);
  }
    
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['drainageid'] = drainageid;
    data['datacount'] = datacount;
    data['resultcount'] = resultcount;
    data['page'] = page;
    if (rows != null) {
      data['rows'] = rows!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Rows {
  String? id;
  DateTime? dateoflastinsp;
  DateTime? dateofinsp;
  String? inspby;

  Rows({this.id, this.dateoflastinsp, this.dateofinsp, this.inspby});

  Rows.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    dateoflastinsp = json['dateoflastinsp'] == null
          ? null
          : DateTime.parse(json['dateoflastinsp'] as String);
    dateofinsp = json['dateofinsp'] == null
          ? null
          : DateTime.parse(json['dateofinsp'] as String);
    inspby = json['inspby'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['dateoflastinsp'] = dateoflastinsp;
    data['dateofinsp'] = dateofinsp;
    data['inspby'] = inspby;
    return data;
  }
}
```

how to change model to list, this is my blocbuilder

```
child: BlocBuilder<ListBloc, listState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is listInitial) {
                return _buildLoading();
              } else if (state is listLoading) {
                return _buildLoading();
              } else if (state is listLoaded) {
              var readmodel = state.listModel.toJson();
              List<listmodel> displaymodel = List.from(readmodel as Iterable);
               void Updatemodel (String value){
                  setState(() { displaymodel = readmodel.entries((element) => 
                  element.drainageid).cast<listmodel>();
//this is wrong actually
                  });
              }

                return _buildListView(context, state.listModel);
              } else if (state is listError) {
                return Container();
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            },
          ),
```

this is my blocbuilder, i intended to put void function in loaded state where model is available, and this is my api response

```
class ApiProvider {
  final Dio _dio = Dio();
  final String _url = 'https://linkishere.com/c&s/drainagepi/all';
  

  Future<listmodel> fetchlistList() async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url, options: Options(headers:{"keyishere":"xxxxxxx"},));
      return listmodel.fromJson(response.data);
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print("Exception occured: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
      return listmodel.withError("Data not found / Connection issue");
    }
  }
}

class ApiRepository {
  final _provider = ApiProvider();

  Future<listmodel>? fetchlistList() {
    return _provider.fetchlistList();
  }
}
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you also add an example of your API response?

Comment: @Berke i have add my api response

Comment: You added request. I mean what server returns you in json? I tried to open the link in request but server is unreachable.